# How to query for all relational objects of an entity in Spring Boot with Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an entity with the following relationship in my Store entity:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="computer")
@JsonProperty("computers")
public Set<Computer> computers;
```

In my StoreService:

```
List<Computers> computers;
Pageable paging = PageRequest.of(page, size);
    
Page<Computers> pageTuts;
pageTuts = storeRepository.findAllComputers(paging);
    
computers = pageTuts.getContent();
    
Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
response.put("computers", computers);
response.put("current_page", pageTuts.getNumber());
response.put("total_items", pageTuts.getTotalElements());
response.put("total_pages", pageTuts.getTotalPages());
```

Now I need to somehow in my **StoreRepository** interface query for all computers that are relational to that entity. How can I do that? I thought I could just add a name like this:

```
Page<Computers> findAllComputers(Pageable pageable);
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Do I have to write a custom Query or something? I think this operation should be some kind of standard so it's hard to think that I would need that.

Comment: I forgot to add useful link to answer. Please see it for the details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create `ComputerRepository` and add this kind of method to your repository class.

```
public interface ComputerRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Computer, Integer> {

    Page<Computers> findByStore(Store store, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Here is quick explanation of Pagination and Sorting.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting